# Parent <div> hides when I click it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input-field, and when I click it a `<div>` will be  shown.
But for some reason when I click on the `<div>`, it hides, and I can't seem to find the issue.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kq9pX/)

```js
$('#searchid').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $("#drope_box").show();
  } else {
    $("#drope_box").hide();
  }
});

$('#searchid').focus(function() {
  $("#drope_box").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner_search_inner_box_search">
  <input type="text" name="search" class="search" id="searchid" onkeyup="getshows();" value="" placeholder="Enter a City,Locality" autocomplete="off">
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<div id="drope_box" style="display:none;">
  <div class="banner_search_type">
    <select id="property_type" name="property_type">
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
      <option value="Plot">Plot</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="banner_search_price_min">
    <select name="price_min" class="search_list" id="price_min">
      <option value="">Price Min</option>
      <option value="100000">1 lac</option>
      <option value="1000000">10 lacs</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="banner_search_price_max">
    <select name="price_max" id="price_max">
      <option value="">Price Max</option>
      <option value="100000">1 lac</option>
      <option value="1000000">10 lacs</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Clicking anywhere outside the input field of course fires its `blur` event … So unless you have entered a value already at that point, your code does exactly what you told it to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're hiding the `<div>` when you lose focus on the input and there is no value.

In your `blur` handler, if the input is empty (as when you first click it), it will hide the dropdown when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

check this I hope that this answered what you have asked for...

```js
$('#searchid').blur(function() {
   if($(this).val() != ""){
        $("#drope_box").hide();    
    }
    else{
        $("#drope_box").show(); 
    }
});

 $('#searchid').focus(function() {
    $("#drope_box").show();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner_search_inner_box_search">
<input type="text" name="search" class="search" id="searchid" onkeyup="getshows();"  value="" placeholder="Enter a City,Locality" autocomplete="off">
<div id="result"></div>
</div>

<div id="drope_box" style="display:none;">
<div class="banner_search_type">
<select id="property_type" name="property_type">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
<option value="Plot">Plot</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="banner_search_price_min">
 <select name="price_min" class="search_list" id="price_min">
  <option value="">Price Min</option>
<option value="100000">1 lac</option>
<option value="1000000">10 lacs</option>
</select>  
</div>
<div class="banner_search_price_max">
 <select name="price_max" id="price_max">
  <option value="">Price Max</option>
<option value="100000">1 lac</option>
<option value="1000000">10 lacs</option>
</select> 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I still want it to hide, when I click outside the `<div>` but not when I click on them.

Comment: yeah just give me a moment I am doing it!

Comment: And I still need to be able to search and click on the shown div